# Reading username and password from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to match username and password entered by the user in the WinForm Application to the username and password stored in the database.
When a user enters a wrong username or password,
I recieve:

> **object reference not set to an instance object**
> *Yes, I know this is not the safest way to save passwords and I'm taking a course on security as at now*

Could anyone help?

Code for the login button

```
private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (isFormValid())
        {
            if (isLoginUsernameCorrect())
            {
                if (isLoginRoleCorrect())
                {
                    if (PublicRole == "Administrator")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Admin Mode", "Administrator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    if (PublicRole == "Secretary")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Secretary Mode", "Secretary", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    if (PublicRole == "Financial")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Financial Mode", "Financial", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Oops, there was an error \n"+"Error: "+ ex.Message,"Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Code for bool isFormValid:

```
private bool isFormValid()
{
    if (txtUsername.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || txtPassword.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User Name and Password both are required..", "Enter User Name and Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

bool isLoginUsernameCorrect() and isLoginRoleCorrect():

```
string PublicRole;
   
private bool isLoginRoleCorrect()
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Access from Userlogins where Username=@user and Credential=@pass", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassword.Text);
    string RoleId = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    PublicRole = RoleId;
    if (RoleId != "Administrator"|| RoleId != "Financial" || RoleId != "Financial")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("UserName or Password is Incorrect.", "Incorrect Login Details", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
  
private bool isLoginUsernameCorrect()
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select username from Userlogins where username=@user and Credential=@pass",con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassword.Text);
    string User = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    if (User == string.Empty.Trim() || User == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and Password", "Incorrect Details", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: First, this is not the correct approach to manage users and passwords. Passwords should never be stored in cleartext in a database. Even if it's not security relevant for your application, somebody will store a password he also uses for his online banking in there...
Second: What exactly is the error? You're checking the value before you check for null, that might cause a problem: if (User == string.Empty.Trim() || User == null)

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, please for the sake of your employer and/or customers *stop* and do some basic research into software development and security practices. You have passwords in your database in plaintext. That is among the most serious possible security violations you could implement. Seriously someone at my employer would be fired on the spot for doing this.

The 'correct' way to manage passwords is to store a cryptographic one-way hash of a salted version of the password in your database. A basic summary of the technique is available here: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/, but honestly, you should probably just go out and take a security course.

Comment: before posting this question, I went through some threads here on SO and found how to store cryptographic one-way hash of a salted version of the password. 
I'm onto that. 
My problem now is, if the user enters a wrong password, The error output is ** "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".**

Comment: @ReubenHale The comment from Shintaro should fix the problem, check for null first